# Android - проблема с MediaPlayer

Tags: android, java, android-mediaplayer

Здравствуйте! Я сделал так, чтобы при нажатии по кнопке в моём приложении раздастся звук щелчка.
При клике делаю так:

---

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
mp.start();
```

---

Но при нажатии на кнопку приложение заметно подтормаживает, звук щелчка проигрывается, а в логах образуется куча сообщений: http://pastebin.com/CezEb8RK . При проигрывании больших файлов такого не происходит. Как можно решить эту проблему, чтобы приложение не подвисало при клике? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Если надо, то вот немного информации o звуке:

```
click.mp3
mono
128kbit/s 
00:01
```

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том что MediaPlayer.Create загружает данные в основном потоке, поэтому подлагивает. Рекомендуется вызывать вместо prepare() - prepareAsync():

```
private void play(Context context, int resid) throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);
        if (afd == null)
            return;
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        afd.close();
        player.prepareAsync();
    }
```